# Hide start time in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

On FullCalendar, in the month view, is there a way to hide an event's start time?

Answer (score 77):

Just add to calendar options

```
displayEventTime: false
```

Comment: This option is available from v2.4.0 see http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventTime - You need to set it as option of fullCalendar and it affects all events. Or use CSS `.fc-time{ display : none; }`. However, I need to set the visibility of each event time differently and it seems that this is not possible.

Answer (score 34):

add the following style to your css

```
.fc-event-time{
   display : none;
}
```

or in version 2+:

```
.fc-time{
   display : none;
}
```

Comment: or `fc-time` as suggested below for the latest version as I noticed for myself.

Answer (score 25):

Try this, it works for me:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     displayEventTime : false
});
```

That should hide the start time in the title event.

Comment: Should be the correct answer. Other answers are just trying to *hide* the issue while here we create the object with correct parameters

Comment: Hi @GangaiJohann wow glad to hear that, I'm happy can help someone :)

Answer (score 16):

To hide them all, the following should work

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 displayEventTime : false
});
```

But if you (like me) were trying to hide the time of a specific event, I found pretty clean way.

Just create the following CSS class and refer to it in the event property "className":

```
.hideCalendarTime > div > span.fc-time{
    display:none;
}
```

And your event should look something like this:

```
var newEvent = new Object();
newEvent.title = "Something";
newEvent.start = new Date();
newEvent.allDay = false;
newEvent.className = "hideCalendarTime";
```

Answer (score 12):

The following hides the date on the month view only:

```
.fc-view-month .fc-event-time{
    display : none;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to add an eventRender function. This way you can choose to not render the time, and do something else like append some data to the event.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.location); 
    element.find('.fc-event-time').hide();
}
```

Comment: This worked after I updated the class names to `.fc-title` and `.fc-time`

Answer (score 6):

remind that the CSS class name has changed to

```
.fc-time {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you completely want to remove the Start time, you can use the below code

```
$('#calendar-canvas').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'today prev,next title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).find(".fc-event-time").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been three months since you asked the question. But, if you and I are trying to do the same thing than someone else may be looking for the answer.

In the fullcalendar.js file, comment line 1603:

```
htmlEscape(formatDates(event.start, event.end, view.option('timeFormat'), options)) +
```

This is not a fix, at best it is a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/ , you just need to set time format in fullCalendar settings:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [              
    ],
    timeFormat: ' '
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time,.fc-time-grid-event .fc-time{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Above code will correct it in all views.

code below has a flow that shows time in large view of event

```
 .fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time{
            display: none !important;
        }
```

please use this code in css to hide the time only from event.

using just

```
.fc-time{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

will also hide the time at left grid.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Riz was correct at the time of posting, the css has changed in recent versions and now you'd need the following.

```
.fc-day-grid-event .fc-time{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `allDay: false,` from your fullCalendar function

Comment: Setting allDay:false creates a problem.
Events are shown wrong when event spawns multi-day

Answer (score 0):

`displayEventTime: false`
but you need to add `allDay=false` in event data resources
`{ "title": "e", "start": "2022-04-17T16:02:21", "allDay": false }`