# How to Hide start time(.fc-time) in week and day view of full calendar Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want to hide the start and end time in week and day view only but not in month view calendar.
if I do something like below

```
            .fc-time{
                    display : none !important;
                  }
```

The above one completely hidden even in month view.Any suggestions how to customize this one only for week and day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the 
[Hide start time in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732132/hide-start-time-in-fullcalendar)

I gone through the html of both month,week and Day view.In case of month .fc-time is used in span and in case of week,day view .fc-time is used in div.
I'm just hiding those as per my requirement.

In case of month Html :-

```
   <div class="fc-content">
    <span class="fc-time">11:30 - 12:00</span>
     <span class="fc-title">Officer Meeting</span>
  </div>
```

In case of week,Day Html:-

```
<div class="fc-content">
<div class="fc-time" data-start="11:30" data-full="11:30 - 12:00">
</div>
<div class="fc-title">Officer Meeting</div></div>
```

Finally here is my solution to hide the .fc-time in week and day but in month.

```
   .fc-content .fc-time {
        display: none !important;
    }
      .fc-content span.fc-time {
       display: inline-block !important;
    }
```